# How to catch the ffmpeg connection error on python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am working on the ffmpeg with python.This works when the remote server is working well, however when the remote server is down, I could see the message on the shell saying 
'Connection to tcp://xxxxxxx failed: Connection refused, blabla'

```
pro = sp.Popen(command, preexec_fn=os.setsid, shell=False, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

catch exception approach 1:

```
try:
   out = self.pro.stderr.readline()
   while out:
            print '......'
except BrokenPipeError:
     print 'err'
```

catch exception approach 2:

```
for line in self.pro.stderr:
    try:
        print line
    except BrokenPipeError:
        print 'error'
```

However none of these works.

Comment: Did you call `Popen.communicate()`?

Comment: yes, i did use Popen.commnicate(), but still nothing works. What makes me felt wield is 'pro = sp.Popen(command, preexec_fn=os.setsid), the shell still outputs the ffmpeg information no matter I added the parameters 'stderr=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE' in the Popen command
'

Answer (score 0):

`communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)` so you just need to print the second element:

```py
cmd = ('ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-i', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:10000', '-c', 'copy', '-f', 'null', '/dev/null');
s = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, preexec_fn=os.setsid, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# print stderr
print s.communicate()[1]
```

Output:

```sh
$ ./test.py 
[tcp @ 0x55a01c945000] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:10000 failed: Connection refused
tcp://127.0.0.1:10000: Connection refused
```